# What is the Most Effective Ground Cover For a Large Area?

Tags: weed-control, ground-cover

What is the cheapest and most effective ground cover and weed blocker for a large area?  I am using black weed blocking sheets but they aren't terribly effective.  I'm not sure how to proceed.  I'm thinking tiles, stone or possibly mulch over the weed blocker, but I know it won't be cheap. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any attractive native or naturalized plant species in your area?

Comment: what part of the world do you live in. What is your budget, how big is the area?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not that effective' - what type of weeds are they? Are they piercing through the membrane in some way?

Comment: @WayfaringStranger  Morning glory is a huge problem, along with your standard nettles, milkweed, dandelions, etc.  As for the area, I will measure and get back to you.

Comment: @Bamboo It's morning glory and something else I can't identify.  Some kind of sprout that is trying to grow through it.  The morning glory mainly grows in patches where it can get just enough sun.  We haven't been able to put anything on top of the weed blocker itself for monetary reasons so we want to do it right once we can.  I live in Utah, by the way.

Comment: In my experience, twining or climbing weeds just head for the nearest bit of daylight and grow through (even with stone on top) and other, sharper weeds may well puncture through the membrane and stones and appear above the lot (Equisitum, Japanese knotweed), so its important you establish quite what weeds you're dealing with first.Sometimes, grass is the best solution - cutting keeps the weeds down.

Comment: The absolute best, usable, inexpensive, beautiful ground cover is 3/8-crushed gravel.  Dig down and grade to accomodate 4".  This is what landscape fabric was created for...NOT WEEDS!  Lay fabric on top of subsoil then fill with gravel/crushed granite.  Use a compactor.  Pea gravel looks nice but is not usable.  You can grow trees in this!  An informal patio...a good blower is all you'll need for maintenance.

Comment: Are you going to be gardening in this area, too, or just covering the ground to prevent weeds?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with the sheets. Try a double layer if you are thinking of using this under a gravel mulch. The mulch should be a minimum 100mm deep.

If you would prefer plants to take over instead, there are many effective species but it does depend on where you are, and what environment it is (ie sunny, part shade, frosts, soil quality). Do you have a photo of the area?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to kill most everything that is already there, before starting fresh with seeds of a groundcover or grass which will grow in thick and not allow any weeds, You can cover the entire area in large sheets of black builders plastic and solarize (bake in the sun)the whole area. It will take six weeks, more to be safe, and the neighbors may think you have lost it. Water the ground heavily before you put the plastic down, (the heat and moisture should make everything sprout that's down there) and wait to do this until its hot, which should be no issue in Utah. I have not found that 'weed barrier' is effective, as anything that is permeable to water, which it has to be to have any plants at all, Is eventually permeable to sprouting plants as well. A really thick layer of gravel is about all I have seen to really prevent weeds, but good gravy is that an ugly solution. Find something that will grow thickly and do some work to get it established, pulling invasive weeds till it fills in, then you should be able to enjoy your outdoor space.